# Generate cross browser CSS3 gradients in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css

As an input I have:

- two colors (be it in hex, rgb or rgba formats), as strings
- a number between 0 and 360 or an angle, in other words

I have to generate a valid, crossbrowser, CSS3 gradients using those parameters. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nkqL6pu6/).

The part with colors is easy, the big pain is the part with converting angle value in a valid direction for every prefix.

I've checked out `amazingSurge/jquery-asGradient` library already and it can do this sort of [manipulations](https://github.com/amazingSurge/jquery-asGradient/blob/master/test/gradient_test.js#L238). But doing CSS generation on client side is not a option for me.

Is there some other PHP libraries that can deal with this?

Comment: do note that about half of the gradient formats in your fiddle are outmoded. to wit the "w3" plain `linear-gradient` works in most places...

Comment: CSS gradients can take angles itself as first parameter. You don't have to convert them to `to [side]` syntax. In fact you cannot convert them because For example, 45 degree is not `to right`, is not `to left`, is `to top right`, is not `to bottom left` or anything.

Comment: @dandavis, good notice, this helps a lot.

Comment: @Harry, Good notice also, I think I'll check just for edge cases. Just like in this [demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Based-Color-Gradient-Picker-asColorPicker/demo/#toc7).